# Livedata returning null in junit test

Tags: android, junit, android-livedata

i have my Room DAO class like this

```
@Dao
interface SourceDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM source_table")
    fun getAllSourceItems(): LiveData<List<Source>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE sourceType = :filterType")
    fun filterSourceItems(filterType:Int): LiveData<List<Source>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertSource(source: Source)

    @Delete
    fun deleteSource(source: Source)

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insertAllSources(sourceList:List<Source>)
}
```

i have tried to write a instrumentation test for one of the methods and it always returning null, i have set the rule as instanttaskexecutorrule but still livedata.value returns null, below is my testing code

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class CreateSourceInstrumentationTest {


    private lateinit var db:AppDatabase

    @get:Rule
    var rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()


    @Before
    fun createDbConnection() {
        val context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<Context>()
        db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java).build()
    }


    @Test
    fun getAllSourceCategoryItems() {
        // test insert a source item

        val testSource = Source("foo", 1)
        db.sourceDao().insertSource(testSource)
        Assert.assertEquals(listOf(testSource), db.sourceDao().getAllSourceItems().value)
    }


    @After
    fun closeDb() {
        db.close()
    }
}
```

getAllSourceCategoryItems() always fails since livedata from dao is null, how to fix this?

Comment: you need to observe `db.sourceDao().getAllSourceItems()`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/core/executor/testing/InstantTaskExecutorRule   InstantTaskExecutor helps to execute synchronously

Comment: it does not matter. you need to observe it

Comment: can you explain why it passes for this test case? https://gist.github.com/naveen17797/416cd70d4626ecf63376463161b807fe

Comment: i didnt observe it in testcase, but it passes

Comment: you aren't using room there as well, are you? Try adding `db.sourceDao().getAllSourceItems().observeForever( )`  as first line in your code and check if it helps

Comment: why do i need to observe it if the call is made synchronous  by instant task executor

Comment: The query to the DB doesn't happen if there's nobody interested in the results

Answer (score 0):

As @blackbelt said in above comment, we need to observe the livedata returned by the method to solve the issue, this libray helped me to test livedata without writing a lot of boiler plate code

https://github.com/jraska/livedata-testing

i have changed my test like this

```
@Test
fun getAllSourceCategoryItems() {
    // test insert a source item

    val testSource = Source("foo", 1)
    db.sourceDao().insertSource(testSource)
    val livedata =  db.sourceDao().getAllSourceItems()
    livedata.test().assertValue(listOf(testSource))

}
```